# How can I to use user selection from list box in one jsp and post results in another jsp?

Tags: jsp

Im working on a project where I need to create an html form with links to my JSP pages and based on the user selection from the list box, pull the matching record from the table. For example, I have a listbox with customer IDs and once the user selects from the box, a second JSP page is pulled reflecting the results. I'm sooooo close I just cant figure out how to get the second form to pull the selection from the first form. Right now it shows all records in the table rather than just the selected. Here is what I have so far for the second jsp page that is supposed to read the selection from the first. Any help would be appreciated as I've been banging my head on this for awhile now. Thanks!!!!

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>

<%
Connection connection = null;
String DBUrl="jdbc:derby://localhost:";

try
{
    String Cid, strSQL, Cname, City, Rating;
    String myCid=request.getParameter("cidform");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DBUrl,"","");
     Statement SQLStatement = connection.createStatement();
     strSQL="select * from customer";
   ResultSet rs = SQLStatement.executeQuery(strSQL);
%>
     <table border='1' width='400' cellspacing=1>
    <thead> 
        <tr> <th>CID</th> <th>Cname</th> <th>City</th> <th>Rating</th>  </tr> 
    </thead>    
<%
while (rs.next())
 {
    Cid=rs.getString("CID");    
            Cname=rs.getString("CNAME");
    City=rs.getString("CITY");
    Rating=rs.getString("Rating");                    
%>
        <tr>
            <td width='25%'><%=Cid%></td>  <td width='25%'><%=Cname%></td>
            <td width='25%'><%=City%></td> <td width='25%'><%=Rating%></td>
        </tr>
<%
       }
       rs.close();
}


catch(SQLException e)
    {
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
out.println("</table>");

    %>

     </table>
```

*** Also Just to add, in the form on .jsp1 I have already set method to post and action to .jsp2

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery (or javascript) to trigger action for `onchange` event on list box. This event should identify the the value selected and create a redirect to url like `second_page.jsp?cust_id=<selected_value>`.

On second page use `request.getAttribute("cust_id")`, and use this for db lookup and subsequent actions.